# Meaning of return statement in recursion

Tags: python

What is the significance of not putting a return statement before the recursive command. What is fundamentally happening when you call the return function vs when you are not?

```
def palin1(a):
    length=len(a)
    if a[0]==a[length-1]:
        return palin1(a[1:length-1])
    else:
        return False
    return True

def palin2(m):
    length=len(m)
    if m[0]==m[length-1]:
        palin2(m[1:length-1])
    else:
        return False
    return True

print(palin1("ramoar"))
print(palin2("ramoar"))
```

False
True

Comment: Please indent your code correctly. Indentation in Python is a syntactic feature. It is not clear what your code, as written, is supposed to do.

Comment: If you are not saving the return of the recursion function anywhere, and it is not directly modifying an object, and you are not returning it 'further' in the recursion, this recursion will be meaningless. It will run 'deep' then back up, and nothing will happen, and it will be futile and the code will effectively ignore everything that happened there. If you are returning it's value, then the function 'goes deep' until it reaches some final return statement, then return backwards 'all the way' back to the first function that called it, and continue from there

Comment: If you pass in a symmetrical string with an even number of letters, both functions will raise an error since the last level will be empty and won't have an index 0.

Comment: Change the m in your input to an o to see what i mean

Answer (score 0):

Two different things occur when return is used:

1.Anything line below 'return' will not execute. The function will stop after the return line.

- in palin1 return True will not execute if return
  palin1(a[1:length-1]) is hit
- in palin2 return True will execute even though palin2(m[1:length-1]) is hit

2.The function call will be replaced with the value.

- in return palin1(a[1:length-1]) the return value will be inserted where the function call occured
- palin2(m[1:length-1]) will cause the function to execute, but
  the value will be thrown away at the end of the function